# No Output and Randomising String Array

Tags: c++, arrays, string

my assignment asks me to open a text file and output a random array and loop it back to the question. I am wondering as why my code has no output? I appreciate all the help I get. Thank you very much.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
srand(time(0));
ifstream fin;
fin.open("songs.txt");
if (!fin.good()) throw "I/O error";
string ans;

const int MAX_SONGS = 200;
int nSongs=0;
string song[MAX_SONGS];


while (fin.good())
{
    // read txt file
    string aSong;
    getline(cin, aSong);

    // add song if still have space
    if (nSongs < MAX_SONGS)
        song[nSongs++] = aSong;
}
fin.close();

cout<<"hi!";
for (int i=0; i<nSongs; i++)
{
    song[i] = (rand() % nSongs);
    cout << " play a song [Y/N]? ";
    getline(cin, ans);
    if (ans=="Y"||ans=="y")
        cout << song[i]<<endl;
    break;
    if (ans=="n"||ans=="N")
        break;

   }


   }
```

Comment: can you see "hi!" on the output ?

Comment: it finally did when I changed the get line to fin instead of cin!

Answer (score 0):

When you read in the file, you are using <kbd>cin</kbd> instead of <kbd>fin</kbd> so you end up reading from the keyboard instead.

```
getline(cin, aSong); // getline(fin,aSong)
```

Normally if the file is just a regular text file with newlines you write it more compact

```
string aSong;
while ( fin >> aSong )
{
  if (nSongs < MAX_SONGS)
   song[nSongs++] = aSong;
}
```

This form

```
while (fin.good())
```

is wrong, because the bit indicating error is set *after* you do getline but you still continue after getline failed.

```
if (nSongs < MAX_SONGS)
    song[nSongs++] = aSong;
```

When you open the file, use the following syntax instead

```
ifstream fin("songs.txt");
if (fin)
{
  ...
}
```

or if you want to keep they way you had it

```
if (!fin)
{
  throw "I/O error";
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
song[i] = (rand() % nSongs);
```

should be

```
int j = (rand() % nSongs);
...
if (ans == "Y" || ans == "y")
{
  cout << song[j] << endl;
```

if you wanted to show a random song.

Comment: Thank you for the insightful and well written comment! The problem I had was with the fin. Once I changed it, the output was shown. I however am still having problem with the for loop down. Could you possibly tell me what I did wrong as when I entered "Y", it just keeps repeating the question and not outputting any array? Thank you.

Comment: I tried adding it, but Im not sure why when I press Y/y it just adds a blank space and keeps repeating the question.. do you think my declaration about the randomising of the array is correct?

Comment: on the rhs you have an int, on the lhs you have a string

Comment: you maybe meant something like `j = (rand()%nSongs); ... cout << song[j] << endl;` ?

Comment: wow thank you so much anders! I really appreciate your help its correct now :) Thank you so much once again!